# module 'mayavi' has no attribute 'points3d'

Tags: python, matplotlib, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I am using a remote server and have installed mayavi using user privileges to make 3D plots.

I am using Jupyter notebook on a cluster and importing mayavi as a library in python3.

To install mayavi, I have used the following:

```
pip install --user mayavi
```

I aslo tried installing PyQt5 but the wheel metadata takes forever to run.

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

n = 5000
x = np.random.rand(n)
y = np.random.rand(n)
z = np.random.rand(n)

mlab.points3d(x, y, z, colormap="RdYlBu", scale_factor=0.02,scale_mode='none', mode='2dcross')
```

However, on running the code, I am getting the following error:

```
module 'mlab' has no attribute 'points3d'
```

Can anyone help with this? I am using python 3.7

Comment: Which version of mayavi are you using?